# Is it still safe to use Sourceforge?

Tags: malware, virus, sourceforge

I noticed some misleading ads on Sourceforge that, if downloaded, will install malware on your computer. Have Sourceforge become a dirty site?

[image: Misleading ad]

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly caused by Sourceforge.  They just use Google Adsense, and somebody has uploaded a Google Adwords advertisement that picks up on the keyword "download" and shows that ad.  You can use the buttons on the top right of the ad to report the ad and Google will take it down.